# How to modify string by index in Clojure?

Tags: string, replace, clojure

I want to modify a string by applying a function to some of its chars (by starting index and length).
For example, I want to increment the ascii representation of the string `"aaaaa"` from the 2nd index to the 4th.

```
[start=1 length=3]
"aaaaa" => "abbba"
```

The only way I could think of is applying `map`, but it goes over all the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `subs` to get the portions you do and don't want to modify. After modification use `str` to concatenate the result together:

```
(defn replace-in-str [f in from len]
  (let [before (subs in 0 from)
        after (subs in (+ from len))
        being-replaced (subs in from (+ from len))
        replaced (f being-replaced)]
    (str before replaced after)))
```

You can call it:

```
(replace-in-str 
 (fn [sub-str] (apply str (map #(char (+ 1 (int %))) sub-str))) 
 "aaaaa" 
 1 
 3)
```

Comment: Yea I though of doing it, but it sounds like an awful lot of work, what do you think about my solution? (described in my answer)

Comment: I wouldn't reach for `map-indexed`, even if it wasn't string substitution being done - in that case I'd use `subvec`.

Comment: Yes it is clear for replace, but what about applying a function?

Comment: Changed the answer so it now calls your example function (called within another function that allows your function to be called every character of the string).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `map` applies the function to every element in the sequence. One way to get around that is to start with `map-indexed`. Unlike `map`, `map-indexed` passes the element's index as the first argument to the mapping function. When we have element's index, we can use it to choose if we need to perform the operation or just return the element as is.

A solution might look like this:

```
(defn inc-char [c]
  (char (inc (long c))))

(defn if-in-range [from to f] 
  (fn [i x & args] 
    (if (<= from i (dec to)) 
      (apply f x args)
      x)))

(defn map-subs [from to f s]
  (apply str (map-indexed (if-in-range from to f) s)))

(map-subs 1 4 inc-char "aaaaa")
;; "abbba"
```

Comment: Yes that was what I also thought of, although I would think clojure had something built-in to handle that...

Answer (score 0):

I thought of using `map-index` to execute the operation only on the specified index:

```
((fn [op start length] (map-indexed (fn [i m] (if (<= start i length)
                         (op m)
                         m)) "aaaaa"))
  #(char (+ 1 (int %)))
  1
  3)

=> (\a \b \b \b \a)
```

Comment: You can wrap the end result with `(apply str ) ` to turn it back into a String btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
(defn replace-str
  [s start-i end-i]
  (apply str (map-indexed (fn [index val]
              (if (and (>= index start-i)
                       (<= index end-i)) 
                  (char (+ (int val) 1))
                  val))
                s)))

(replace-str "aaaa" 1 2)
;=> "abba"
```